# Archimesh units do not calculate to project scene units. inches/meters issue

Tags: units, archimesh-add-on

I'm having some difficulty getting Archimesh units to match to the same units in blender's scene settings.  Archimesh still adds rooms/walls with a default height of 2.4 units no matter if that is meters or feet. the same size mesh is created.  Is there anyway to make Archimesh output on Feet/inches respectively?